# In org-mode, can I include a horizontal separator in a result table generated by an Emacs Lisp code block?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I have some Emacs Lisp code blocks in an Org file which I evaluate to get tables of results.  It would be nice if I could include horizontal separators to separate individual lines of data from headers and summary lines, because that makes it easier to use `org-sort`.  Concretely, I have something like this:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
'((foo bar baz) (1 2 3) (4 5 6))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
| foo | bar | baz |
|   1 |   2 |   3 |
|   4 |   5 |   6 |
```

but it would be nice if I could make the output automatically format itself more like this:

```
#+RESULTS:
| foo | bar | baz |
|-----+-----+-----|
|   1 |   2 |   3 |
|   4 |   5 |   6 |
```

Is there an easy way to do this?  I thought that including `nil` in place of a row of results might do the trick, but it seems not to do the trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at `org-babel-get-colnames`, the easiest way to do this probably is adding an `hline` as second element of your list:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
'((foo bar baz) hline (1 2 3) (4 5 6))
#+END_SRC

#+results:
| foo | bar | baz |
|-----+-----+-----|
|   1 |   2 |   3 |
|   4 |   5 |   6 |
```

Comment: Exactly what I was hoping for! Thanks.